# Interpreting the results of the Dunn test

Tags: interpretation, stata, dunn-test

I've seen some answers that come close to what I'm asking but not quite. I've run a Kruskall-Wallis test that rejected the null hypothesis. Now, I've run the Dunn test, but I'm wondering if I am interpreting it correctly. My results follow:

[image: Dunn test]

As you can see, the pairwise comparison was significant for all comparisons in the Dunn test. My question here regards the ranking. From what I gather, this outcome means that the White rate was significantly higher than the rest of the race's rates (looking at the Rank Sum column of the KW test). Is that a misinterpretation of the rank sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this test, the null hypothesis for each pairwise comparison is that the probability of observing a random rate in the first group that is larger than a random rate in the second group equals one half. Here you reject that for all pairs of races, though you might want to use some sort of multiple comparison adjustment. On its own, I don't think this says anything about different means in the populations.

If you can assume that rate is continuous and the distributions for all groups are identical except for a shift in centrality, then this test can be interpreted as a test of median differences. Similarly, you will need [additional, stronger, assumptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness#Relationship_of_mean_and_median) about the distribution to say something about the mean.

Also, you probably want to show code itself, and not just the output when you ask questions. At the very least, you should mention that you are using a user-written command that was published in the Stata Journal, `dunntest`. This will make your question both easier to answer and will make it more useful for posterity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have set the Dunn test to use the Benjamini-Yekuteili multiple-comparison adjustment. The distributions across races aren't equal, unfortunately.

I apologize for not including the code. I typically do on other SE pages, but didn't know if it was truly necessary in an interpretation question.

I think my hangup is the meaning of the KW Rank Sum in the top table. Does it make sense to use the rank sum to determine which race had the greatest amount of high rates (strange wording, I know)?

Comment: @RossWardrup I missed the B-Y parenthetical in the output. Both the top table are using the same ranking of the rates (instead of the underlying values) and then summing (first) or averaging (second). Unfortunately, you cannot say anything about which race has the highest mean/median/mode of the rate without auxiliary assumptions about the symmetry, mode, and skew of the underlying rate distributions. Without this, you can only say something about the ranking if you were to pluck a member of each group at random and compared their rates. This is the cost of nonparametric methods.

Comment: @RossWardrup The top table is just a `kwallis` test. It's an omnibus test, so  it can tell you that at least two groups are from a different population when you fail it, but not which ones or what's different. If you add in the continuity plus centrality assumption, you can also interpret it as difference in medians test, but it still doesn't tell you a whole lot.