# How do identical distributions "except for a shift in centrality" look like?

Tags: distributions

[In this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236876/interpreting-the-results-of-the-dunn-test/390890?noredirect=1#comment733929_390890), someone mentions that a Kruskal Wallis test can be interpreted as a test of median differences, provided that...

> "you can assume that rate is continuous and the distributions for all groups are identical except for a shift in centrality".

My knowledge in statistics is not very advanced and I am wondering what this means. I don't understand how a change in centrality (meaning a change in mean / median, right?) can *not* change the distribution type.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[image: distributions]

The first case is one where both distributions are identical except for a shift. (Since they are otherwise identical, the additional "in centrality" is redundant.) In the second case, we have the same *type* of distribution (both are normal), but they are not only shifted, their variances also differ. In the third case, we have different *types* of distribution, a normal and a $\chi^2$.

R code:

```
xx <- seq(-5,5,by=.01)
par(las=1,mfrow=c(3,1),mai=c(.5,.5,.5,.1))

plot(xx,dnorm(xx,-1),type="l",lwd=2,xlab="",ylab="",main="Shift in centrality")
lines(xx,dnorm(xx,1),lwd=2,col="red")

plot(xx,dnorm(xx,-1),type="l",lwd=2,xlab="",ylab="",main="Shift in centrality and different variance")
lines(xx,dnorm(xx,1,2),lwd=2,col="red")

plot(xx,dnorm(xx,-1),type="l",lwd=2,xlab="",ylab="",main="Different distributions",ylim=c(0,0.6))
lines(xx,dchisq(xx,2),lwd=2,col="red")
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an oversimplification, but still an example:

$\mathcal{N_1}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$

Consider two normal distributions, defined by $\mathcal{N_1}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$  and $\mathcal{N_2}(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)$.

If you have $\mu_1=\mu_2$ and $\sigma_1=\sigma_2$ the two are identical.

However, if $\mu_1\neq\mu_2$, they are not identical anymore, because their centres are different. This is what one could call "identical except for a shift in centrality" in a more colloquial language.

Comment: You can use LaTeX: `$\mathcal{N}$` gives $\mathcal{N}$.